# php sessions, adding url links to users favourites

Tags: php, session, url

I'm trying to design a site which shows the user a number of different items, i would like for them to be able to add the items they choose to a 'view later' page, basically like a add to favourites.
When they go to the page i would like the item to be displayed as a link which will take them back to the item viewed.
I don't want the users to have to sign up for the site therefore can't store the selections in a database,is there any easy way to do this in PHP. i've been puzzling over this for the last 3 days, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you using a database of some sort? Do users log in or are they just "guests"?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data on their computer with either Cookies or HTML5 localstorage. See if this example helps.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="item" id="item1">Item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="item" id="item2">Item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="item" id="item3">Item 3</a>
```

**JS**

```
var viewedItems = [];

$(".item").click(function() {
   viewedItems.push($(this).attr("id"));
   localStorage['viewedItems'] = JSON.stringify(viewedItems)
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   console.log('viewedItems: ', JSON.parse(localStorage['viewedItems']));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kvZsP/)

You can retrieve this array anywhere on your site and show the user the items they have previously "saved" in it. localstorage is saved on the user's computer so it'll only be accessible from there, in that browser, and only to your site.